# Extract nested list elements using bracketed numbers and names

Tags: r

After running a repeated measures ANOVA and naming the output

```
RM_test <- ezANOVA(data=test_data, dv=var_test, wid = .(subject),
within = .(water_year), type = 3)
```

I looked at the internal structure of the named object using `str(RM_test)` and received the following:

```
List of 3
$ ANOVA                        :List of 3
..$ ANOVA                        :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  7 variables:
.. ..$ Effect: chr "water_year"
.. ..$ DFn   : num 2
.. ..$ DFd   : num 22
.. ..$ F     : num 26.8
.. ..$ p     : num 1.26e-06
.. ..$ p<.05 : chr "*"
.. ..$ ges   : num 0.531
..$ Mauchly's Test for Sphericity:'data.frame': 1 obs. of  4 variables:
.. ..$ Effect: chr "water_year"
.. ..$ W     : num 0.875
.. ..$ p     : num 0.512
.. ..$ p<.05 : chr ""
..$ Sphericity Corrections       :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  7 variables:
.. ..$ Effect   : chr "water_year"
.. ..$ GGe      : num 0.889
.. ..$ p[GG]    : num 4.26e-06
.. ..$ p[GG]<.05: chr "*"
.. ..$ HFe      : num 1.05
.. ..$ p[HF]    : num 1.26e-06
.. ..$ p[HF]<.05: chr "*"
$ Mauchly's Test for Sphericity:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
..$ Effect: chr "wtr_yr"
..$ W     : num 0.875
..$ p     : num 0.512
..$ p<.05 : chr ""
$ Sphericity Corrections       :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  7 variables:
..$ Effect   : chr "wtr_yr"
..$ GGe      : num 0.889
..$ p[GG]    : num 4.26e-06
..$ p[GG]<.05: chr "*"
..$ HFe      : num 1.05
..$ p[HF]    : num 1.26e-06
..$ p[HF]<.05: chr "*"
```

I was able to extract the fourth variable `F` from the first data frame using `RM_test[[1]][[4]][1]` but cannot figure out how to extract the third variable `p[GG]` from the data frame `Sphericity Corrections`. This data frame appears twice so extracting either one would be fine.

Suggestions on how to do this using bracketed numbers and names would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be you not knowing how to extract list elements. As you said, there are two `Sphericity Corrections` data frames, so I will how to get the `p[GG]` value for both.

**using bracketed number**

For the first one, we do `RM_test[[1]][[3]][[3]]`. You can do it step by step to understand it:

```
x1 <- RM_test[[1]]; str(x1)
x2 <- x1[[3]]; str(x2)
x3 <- x2[[3]]; str(x3)
```

For the second one, do `RM_test[[3]][[3]]`.

**using bracketed name**

Instead of using numbers for indexing, we can use names. For the first, do

```
RM_test[["ANOVA"]][["Sphericity Corrections"]][["p[GG]"]]
```

For the second, do

```
RM_test[["Sphericity Corrections"]][["p[GG]"]]
```

**using `$`**

For the first one, do

```
RM_test$ANOVA$"Sphericity Corrections"$"p[GG]"
```

For the second one, do

```
RM_test$"Sphericity Corrections"$"p[GG]"
```

Note the use of quote `""` when necessary.

Comment: All of the bracketed number solutions returned "Error in RM_test[[i]][[1]][[3]][[3]] : subscript out of bounds".  However, the bracketed name solution RM_test[["Sphericity Corrections"]][["p[GG]"]] worked perfectly.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: My apologies, this is part of a for-loop and these elements are extracted with each ith iteration of the loop.  When I use RM_test[[i]][["Sphericity Corrections"]][["p[GG]"]] this works perfectly.  Thanks for the feedback.